# How to sum specific dictionary value in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on nodejs. How to sum of amount which has the dictionary key value of Senior from the list dictionary?

```
traveler =  [
     {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
     {  description: 'Senior', Amount: 50},
     {  description: 'Adult', Amount: 75},
     {  description: 'Child', Amount: 35},
     {  description: 'Infant', Amount: 25 },
 ];

expected result = {"senior": 100, "Adult":75}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reduce function like the following:

```
traveler.reduce((prevValue, t) => {
    return Object.assign(prevValue, { [t.description]: (prevValue[t.description] || 0) + t.Amount })
}, {});
```

Read about reduce function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: You're getting only the unique . You didn't sum of the unique values which is having the amount

Comment: I did. You can check.

Comment: I tried the above logic. Senior value getting only 50 . But actual expected value Senior :100;

Comment: I'm sorry about that, missed a couple of parentheses. Added them now. 